# How return list object to show in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have controller where I use service. That service do some querys and return **List** like this:
[image]

**Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult GetTareas(string tiporesponsable, int responsableID, int? cuadrillaID, int? sucursalID, int regionID, int solicitudID, string chkFinalizadas)
 {
    var consulta = ag.ConsultarAgenda(tiporesponsable, responsableID, 
     cuadrillaID, sucursalID, regionID, solicitudID, chkFinalizadas);   
    return View();
 }
```

Now I want to get some value of that service `(ag.ConsultarAgenda)` for example: `"SucursalCodigo"` and receive into view into div like:

```
<div id="event_box" class="margin-bottom-10"></div>
```

Can anyone explain me how can I do it? Regards

Can I do sending `Json`? like:

```
 return Json(consulta, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

but How can I receive specific object into view?

Comment: First thing I'd do is find a tutorial on how to use MVC. Microsoft has several, including [Adding a View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-view)...

Comment: You can assign your list value to viewbag to show in view

Comment: then you can write @foreach for your viewbag in view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC offers us several options for passing data from controller to view upon request, one of them is ViewBag.
As of your example above you can do the following in the controller part:

```
 public ActionResult GetTareas(string tiporesponsable, int responsableID, int? cuadrillaID, int? sucursalID, int regionID, int solicitudID, string chkFinalizadas)
    {
  ViewBag.ConsultarAgenda = ag.ConsultarAgenda(tiporesponsable, responsableID, 
 cuadrillaID, sucursalID, regionID, solicitudID, chkFinalizadas);   
        return View();
    }
```

And in the view :

```
<div id="event_box" class="margin-bottom-10">@ViewBag.ConsultarAgenda</div>
```

The best practice to consume Json is via AJAX on the frontend(The View):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("GetTareas", "ControllerName")',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){
  //consume the returned data here
   $(".margin-bottom-10").html(data);
  },
  error: errorFunc});
</sript>
<div id="event_box" class="margin-bottom-10"></div>
```

Comment: When I consume it via ajax, how can I call it in view?

Comment: You can use jquery to manipulate the view as the example above.

Comment: Yes, ad don´t forget to use `JSON.stringify(data)` because I receive an object so we need to convert it to string

Answer (score 0):

A ViewBag should work:

@ViewBag.TexttoLargo

You may want to parse the ViewBag result as it it looks like it is terminated with a return.

Comment: you should use JsonResult if you want to return Json in controller

Answer (score 0):

As  Mike McCaughan mentioned you should go throught some tutorials.

You have multiple options based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller)

### ViewBag

The ViewBag is a dynamic object that provides a convenient late-bound way to pass information to a view

### @model Keyword

Strongly typed class.
example

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
    if (movie == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(movie);
}
```

then accessing model in view:
[image: view]